# Why i can't use foreach two times in one page?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I just start to learn php and I have this problem when I try to use `foreach` twice in my script I get this error:

> "Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\MAMP\htdocs\blog\app\Database.php on line 29
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\MAMP\htdocs\blog\app\Database.php:34 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\blog\app\Table\Article.php(15): App\Database->query('\r\n SELEC...', 'App\Table\Artic...') #1 C:\MAMP\htdocs\blog\pages\home.php(10): App\Table\Article::getLast() #2 C:\MAMP\htdocs\blog\public\index.php(20): require('C:\MAMP\htdocs\...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\blog\app\Database.php on line 34"

But when I use foreach one time it works fine.
This is the code I use:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
   <ul>
     <?php foreach(\App\Table\Categorie::all() as $categorie): ?>
         <li><a href="<?= $categorie->getUrl(); ?>"><?= $categorie->name;?></a></li>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?php foreach(\App\Table\Article::getLast() as $post): ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
```

```
public static function getLast()
{
 return App::getDb()->query("
 SELECT articles.id_article, articles.nom_article, articles.object, articles.photo, category.name as categorie  
 FROM articles 
 LEFT JOIN category 
 ON category_id = category_category_id
 ", __CLASS__);
}
```

Database

```
enter code here
public function query($statement, $class_name, $one = false)
{
    $req = $this->getPDO()->query($statement);
    $req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class_name);
    if($one)
    {
        $data = $req->fetch();
    }
    else 
    {
        $data = $req->fetchAll();
    }
    return $data;
}'
```

function all

```
private static $table = 'category';

public static function all()
{
    return App::getDb()->query("
        SELECT * 
        FROM " .self::$table ."
        ", __CLASS__);
}
```

Comment: According to error problem is in database.php file

Comment: Have you tried with only 2nd foreach loop? I don't think you problem is the foreach loops its the query you are using to get data from database.

Comment: It seems that after the first `foreach` you are closing your connection(assigning it to `null`) and then for the second `foreach` you do not have any connection. It this really your complete code you you have minified it?

Comment: Can you also please add the code for `Categorie::all()` method to your question?

Comment: Also, looking at your error and your code you have this `query('\r\n SELEC...'` in your error code, which means you have and `\r\n` at the beginning of your query, So please change your query and delete the `\r\n`(enter) in the beginning and see if you get same error or not...

Comment: I try your suggestion I stell have the same problem

Comment: So I've managed to download `GuindailleFacile`, Your code is different from this application. So I think you have made some changes in it. Can you please share what you have at line 29 of `app\Database.php`? Because in original version at this line we have `$this->db_pass = $db_pass;` which has nothing to do with `pdo`

Comment: $req = $this->getPDO()->query($statement);

Comment: Unfortunately debugging your code is not possible like this. I don't know how, but if I can access all of your code completely, then maybe I can find the origin of your problem. Maybe you can upload your complete code somewhere if it's possible for you. Because again the original version of the application does not have `$categorie->getUrl();` or other changes you have made in the app...

Comment: Ok I will put it in github and thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/AbderrazzakB/Article

Comment: How about your database structure? At least you also have changes table name `categories` to `category`. Can you please add a dump of you database to your git?

Comment: Ok I did it, Thank you for your time

Comment: :) No problem. I've posted an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, your problem is that in the `getPDO()` method, you are checking `if($this->pdo === null){` then create a connection to the database. But when in the same script you want to use `getPDO()` because `$this->pdo` is not `null` and it's actually a connection to databse, so is does not enter the `if` block, so the `$pdo` variable does not get declared.

The solution is very easy. You just need to add an `else` section to your `if`

So in your `app\Database.php` file, change the `private function getPDO()` to this:

```
private function getPDO() {
    if($this->pdo === null){
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost', 'root', '');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo = $pdo;  
    }
    else{
        $pdo = $this->pdo;
    }
    return $pdo;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's work, I need to learn more about php do you know any helpful resource.

Comment: :) you are welcome. Unfortunately No, Google, SO and php documentation will help you a lot...